# IE11 Enterprise Mode enabled (GPO): does not show up in Group Policy Manager

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I have Enterprise Mode configured on the DC, via GPO. I've made sure the PCs have KB2929437 installed.

Within the XML:

```
<rules version="2">
  <docMode>
    <domain docMode="9">extendedcare.com</domain>
  </docMode>
</rules>
```

But when visiting websites listed in the XML, the doc mode is stuck on default (Edge) and not what Enterprise Mode's XML is indicating. See below. What am I missing?

[image: Local PC has KB installed]

[image: GPO setting on the DC]

[image: Website tested, doc mode not set as Enterprise Mode should be doing]

I did the above in Local Group Policy Editor.

If I go into Group Policy Management Editor, the option does not even show up:

[image: No enterprise mode policy]

Comment: You're missing the part where you check if the settings are enabled on the endpoint. Try running gpresult /h gpresult.html.  Also make sure the sitelist is actually accessible, and try specifying a local file to see if that works.

Comment: @GregAskew It does not show up in gpresult, even though I've tried a gpupdate. Am I missing something in my steps? Do I need to do something in "Group Policy Management" as well?

Comment: Where is the GPO linked, and what security principals are in the Scope tab?

Comment: @GregAskew I made an edit to my OP. In local edit, the option to enable shows up. In GPME it does not, which seems to be my real issue.

Comment: If the setting does not appear in Group Policy Management Console editor, how did you enable the setting in a GPO?

Comment: @GregAskew I was editing in "Local" before. I am now editing in GPME, where it does not show up.